# How to export environment variable without typing its default name?

Tags: bash, shell

Take CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES for example (long name). It takes time to type it every time in the terminal.

Is there a way to replace

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
```

with smth shorter?

Comment: Assuming that there exists such a "alias" for environment variables (it doesn't), could you show how you would use it? Perhaps there is a solution, which is not a name alias, but works well enought for your purpose.

Comment: @user1934428 Please help me to find the proper name for the potential solution.

Comment: if there's only this line that you end up using often, you might as well define this function in your bashrc: `exportCDV() { export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0; }`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function in the bashrc:

```
cvd() { export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$1; }
export -f cvd
```

Then call from the terminal

```
cvd 0,5

echo $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES
0,5
```

Based on the comment above.